# Confirmation app on iPhone URL Scheme

Tags: objective-c, xcode, twitter

Hey developpers,
I need to ask a confirmation on the [iPhone URL Scheme](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes). Is the URL Scheme '[Tweetie](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Tweetie)' the Official Twitter application? I know in the website it said that there were Twitterriffic / Twitterriffic Premium, Twittelator Pro and Tweetie but for Tweetie, it's unsual to me the way it's said. It's like it's a built iPhone app (not the Official Twitter iPhone application), but after searching for Tweetie on the app store, it appears there is no such app called 'Tweetie', so I just need to know from someone if this is the [Official Twitter app](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/twitter/id333903271?mt=8). So hope someone can help me out, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, that is the official Twitter app.